# Benefits of SQLAlchemy ORM vs its engine?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Trying to figure out what the benefit of using the SQL Alchemy Engine to write raw sql queries is vs just doing raw sql queries. And the benefit of using their ORM vs just using the engine in regards to speed?

Comment: Good question +1.I would be interested in the replies.